# XML serialize - remove first default tag

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have the following class:

```
public class RecordDTO
{       
   public int TabIndex { get; set; }      
   public int TaxYear { get; set; }       
}
```

I serialize an instance of the class:

```
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(record.GetType());
        string xmlstring = null;
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            x.Serialize(writer, record);
            xmlstring = writer.ToString();
        }
```

The result is:

```
 "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <RecordDTO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <TabIndex>1</TabIndex>
    <TaxYear>2014</TaxYear>
 </RecordDTO>"
```

**I want the first row** `(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>)` **to not be created at the xmlstring.**
**What should I do?**

**About the 'duplicate' claim of rene, Unihedron, Infinite Recursion, har07, Athari:
The other question use xmlWriter, and I need stringWriter.
If you have way to do it by stringWriter; or you have a way to use xmlWriter and accept string - you can tell about.**

Comment: You consistently spell "serialize" correctly inside of the code, but consistently misspell it in your own writing. If you are using copypasta code without understanding it, the first thing to do is get a C# reference book.

Comment: But it is for xmlWriter and I use stringWriter